# Informix 11.50 hierarchical SQL

Tags: sql, informix, hierarchical-data

I need a little help with informix 11.50 hierarchy data SQL. I have the following table:

```
create table cont_reln (
    contact char(10),
    relation_type char(1),
    related_to char(10));

contact   | relation_type   | related_to
1000        CH                2001
1000        CH                2002
1000        CH                2003
2001        CH                3001
2001        CH                3002
2002        CH                3003
2003        CH                3004
3004        CH                4001
4001        CH                5001
```

I've written the two SQLs that can take a contact and figure out all the parents, and all the children:

```
-- Get the children
SELECT contact, related_to, LEVEL
   FROM cont_reln
      START WITH contact = '?'
      CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR  related_to = contact
   ORDER SIBLINGS BY related_to;   

-- Get the parents
SELECT contact, related_to, LEVEL    
   FROM cont_reln
    START WITH related_to = '?'    
      CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR contact = related_to
   ORDER SIBLINGS BY contact;
```

Each of these queries return what I'm after, but I'm unsure how to combine them in order to get the following output when I START WITH any contact number... So, no matter what '?' is, if it's somewhere in this hierarchy, the dataset will return exactly the same as below:

```
contact   | relation_type   | related_to
NULL        NULL              1000
1000        CH                2001
2001        CH                3001
2001        CH                3002
1000        CH                2002
2002        CH                3003
2003        CH                3004
3004        CH                4001
4001        CH                5001
```

I know the first row (with the nulls) would have to be returned as a separate hardcoded return in the SP once I know the root node, but from line 2 -> onwards I'm not sure how to do it.

Any ideas?

** EDIT **
The query to find the parent was incorrect - fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

It's not possible to do this in one query, but inside a stored procedure it's trivial.

Firstly, I needed to know the root node (it had nothing to do with combining two queries).

To find the root node I run:

```
SELECT 
  contact
FROM 
  cont_reln
WHERE 
  relation_type = 'CH'
  START WITH related_to = '?'
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE 
    PRIOR contact = related_to 
    AND PRIOR related_to != related_to
ORDER SIBLINGS BY 
  contact
```

This is in a foreach, and by virtual of the way the hierarchical query returns, I always know the last record is the root.

From there, I just run the child select based on the root contact id.

```
SELECT 
  contact, 
  related_to
FROM 
  cont_reln
WHERE 
  relation_type = 'CH'
  START WITH contact = 'THE RETURNED ROOT NODE ID'
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR  related_to = contact
ORDER SIBLINGS by 
  related_to
```